# Css transition ignore the animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have this css transition, I want to make disappear a div right to left and that the width is reduced little by little:

```
.disapear {
   transition: width 1s ease-in;
   width: 0px;

}

  .img-thumb {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 1.5em 0;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

the effect is not animated, and the element disappears abruptly

this is my html:

```
<div class="img-thumb">
 <img src="myimage.jpg">
</div>
```

the class **.disapear** is added after clicking on the element

what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: We need to see your code to reproduce the issue. Although if your element does not have a defined width (like `width: auto`), CSS cannot animate from `auto` to `0`.

Comment: @Pete I edit the main post

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I edited the main post

Comment: Put `width: 100%;` inside the `.img-thumb` rule (or any value that isn't a keyword like `auto`), place the `.disapear` (missing a p!) ruleset after, and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your element is inline-block, I would animate the max width.  js below is just to add your disapear class (you haven't shown how it gets added)

```css
.img-thumb {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 1.5em 0;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: max-width 1s ease-in;
  
  overflow:hidden;   /* add these 2 */
  max-width:100%;  /* may want to change this to be width of your image to remove the delay from the beggining of the animation */
}

.disapear {  /* this needs to appear after the above style */
  max-width: 0px;
  border: 0;     /* hide border */
}
```

```html
<div class="img-thumb" onclick="this.classList = 'img-thumb disapear';">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</div>
```